# How to make NSButton of NSAlert crops the text?

Tags: swift, macos, nsbutton, nsalert

My NSAlert has 2 buttons. I changed the font of a button but its frame doesn't auto-resize to crops its text.
I have tried changing the frame of the button, use sizeToFits, set attribute title, ... but it didn't work.
How can I make the button to crops the text? Is it possible? Thanks.

Here is a screenshot of the button:

[image: button screenshot]

I use this code to change the button's font:

```
alert.buttons[0].font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25.5)
```

Comment: What does to make a button crop its title text mean?

Comment: I want to make nsbutton bigger to fit the text "Deny". Like button "Open System Preference" at default font

Comment: You need to make your own `NSButton` subclass, then.